# How to make position absolute responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, next.js, media-queries

I am building a site in NEXTJS. I have a position absolute on a textbox. When I make the screen smaller the text box stretches all the way to the nav bar rather than staying in its background image.

You can see it https://wycombe-hive.vercel.app/.

I am not sure how to make it responsive for smaller screens.  This is the CSS I have now for the text box

```
.centeredtwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 85%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;

 
}
```

Comment: Where is the textbox on the page?

Comment: Provide a minimal reproduction sample